# How to show matching rows of two columns in a multi index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, multi-index

I want to show the matching rows from sub_col1 and sub_col2 having a multi index dataframe.
How can I do so?

Here is my dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [("r0", "rA"), ("r1", "rB"), ("r4", "rB")], names=["Courses", "Fee"]
)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("col1", "sub_col1"), ("col2", "sub_col2")])
data = [[100, 300], [200, 500], [500, 200]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols, index=multi_index)
```

I want to go from this:

[image]

to this expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
# Check for corresponding values
df[("col2", "sub_col2")] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x[("col1", "sub_col1")]
    if x[("col1", "sub_col1")] in df[("col2", "sub_col2")].tolist()
    else x[("col2", "sub_col2")],
    axis=1,
)

# Reorder the dataframe
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df[df[("col1", "sub_col1")] == df[("col2", "sub_col2")]],
        df[df[("col1", "sub_col1")] != df[("col2", "sub_col2")]],
    ]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```py
      col1     col2
  sub_col1 sub_col2
0      200      200
1      500      500
2      100      300
```